# How map stream to immutable java class?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Consider a piece of code:

```
imnport reactor.util.context.Context

public Context addAll (Context ctx, Map.Entry<String, Object> hashMap) {
    Context ctxVar = ctx;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> e : hashMap.entrySet()) {
        if (e.getValue() != null) {
            ctxVar = ctxVar.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }
    }
    return ctxVar;
}
```

`reactor.util.context.Context` is immutable class. So `put` merges old context with new added value and returns **new**
context.

The question is - is there more compact way to "combine" HashMap into immutable object using java 8 streams? (Not for Context class only)

Note: I have read about java stream collect and it seems that does not work because I have to supply initial `Context`
and combine several contexts after map but recreate entire context for combine operations I think is too much.

Comment: Shouldn't `Map.Entry<String, Object> hashMap` be `Map<String, Object> hashMap`? You use that variable as if it's a `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce`:

```
Context ctxVar = hashMap.entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .filter(e -> e.getValue() != null)
                        .reduce(ctx,
                                (c, e) -> c.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()),
                                (c1, c2) -> c1.putAll(c2));
```

It does seem wasteful, though (in the same way your original loop is wasteful), since it creates multiple `Context` instances when only the last one is needed.

It would make more sense if you write a `static` method of the `Context` class (or a constructor) that accepts a `Map` and only creates a single `Context` instance for the entries of the `Map`. However, I now noticed that you didn't write this `Context` class, so you can't change it.

Comment: It's a bit long winded but... you could implement a mutable version of `Context` which accumulates (key, value) pairs, build it up while streaming the map and then hand it over to the provided context with `context.addAll( myMutableContext)`

Comment: @DavidSoroko Your approach will iteratively create a new `Context` for each entry from `Context`(containing previous entries) provided as a parameter to `Context.putAll`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question interested me. I researched the subject.

Here is what I came up with:

```
package reactor.util.context;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

public class ContextUtils {
    public static Context putAll(Context context, Map map) {
        if (map.isEmpty()) {
            return context;
        } else {
            Map contextMap = context.stream()
                                    .filter(e -> e.getValue() != null)
                                    .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
            return new ContextN(contextMap, map);
        }
    }
}
```

This utility method creates a new `Context` containing the entries from both initial context and provided map.

This solution may still look not optimal, as it creates a new `HashMap` with *initiaCapacity = 0* and *loadFactor = 0.75f*. In fact, this is not a problem, since `ContextN` itself is a subclass of `HashMap` with precise capacity and *loadFactor = 1*. The data from intermediary map will be copied to the context and later it will be collected by GC.

**Note**: the utility class has to be in package `reactor.util.context`. `ContextN` is `package-private` so it is not accessible from other packages.